# Using 'any' tag mode breaks the 'no answer'/'needs answer' filters

Tags: bug, ios-app

In the iOS app (I don't have the Android app with me to test if it happens there too), filtering questions by 'no answer' with *multiple tags* works if you have the 'tag mode' set to 'all':

[image]

However, setting the 'tag mode' to 'any' causes the 'no answer' filter to be ignored:

[image]

In that second screenshot, the 'no answer' filter is behaving as if it was set to 'all'. The 'needs answer' filter has the same problem.

- App Version: 1.5.3.5
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 9.3.2 (Build 13F69)